# Rename the "New Item" text in SPO list New Form to a meaningful Title

Tags: sharepoint-online, splist, newform

in my new form.aspx of my splist  of my SPO site, i would like to change the title `New Item` to "some_meaningfull_name"(like create customer , or create product etc ) , is this possible?
since its not classic experience , i  cant add a JQuery code or JS code or i dont have an option to edit the page too.

is there any way, i can achieve this?

[image: RENAME_NEW-ITEM-splistform-newform]

Comment: have you done this already? i am also looking on how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You are able to do it, but it is a bit roundabout.

**Pro tip: If you haven't used PowerApps to customize forms before now, I highly recommend going through the intro tutorial that should popup when you first load the page**

1. On the screen shown, click the "Customize Button" and you will redirect to PowerApps.
2. (Optional) Hide any fields you do not what to show by flipping the toggle switch under the properties (Right hand side).
3. Navigate to *Insert > Label*
4. Type the desired label (some_meaningful_name)
5. Update the "Size" and "FontWeight" properties (and any other settings you would like to change
6. Navigate to *File > Save*
7. On the PowerApps page, click "Back to SharePoint" in the top left corner.

Comment: your approach doesn't seem to work, the New Item is still there.